# While executing the code I got compile error: Expect End With

Tags: excel, vba

While executing the code I got the following error , "Expect End With " . It could be great , if help is provided .

I have created the code below that compare two spreadsheets . It initially compares the range of value from sheet1 ("Status") to sheet2 ("Interface") . Whenever a range matches with the ranges present in other sheet , it does nothing .When the range does not any matches in the other sheet , then the entire record is copied from sheet2 to sheet1 . I have around 1500 rows of data in both sheets with 15 columns .

```
Function UpdateNEW2() As Long
    Const Delimiter As String = "|"
    Dim dic As Object
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim newRows As Range
    Dim vSteps, key
    With Sheets("Steps")
        vSteps = .Range("A2:C2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With

        Dim r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
        For r = 1 To UBound(vSteps)
            key = vSteps(r, 2) & Delimiter & vSteps(r, 2)
            If Not dic.Exists(key) Then dic.Add key, 0
        Next

        Dim vInterface, results
        With Sheets("Interface")
            vInterface = .Range("A2:O2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Value
        End With

        ReDim results(1 To UBound(vInterface), 1 To 15)
        For r = 1 To UBound(vInterface)
            key = vInterface(r, 5) & Delimiter & vInterface(r, 5)
            If Not dic.Exists(key) Then
                n = n + 1
                For c = 3 To 15
                    results(n, c - 2) = vInterface(r, c)
                Next
            End If
        Next
        With Sheets("Steps")
        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .Resize(n, 15).Value = results
                  End With

              UpdateNEW2 = n

    End Function
```

Comment: You don't have an `end with` for your `with sheets("steps")` block

Comment: I am still getting the error . I am not a expert in VBA . Could you explain them

Comment: Works for me (doesn't error at least).

Comment: When the worksheet is empty . I get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit '<- Always use Option Explicit 

Function UpdateNEW2() As Long

    Const Delimiter As String = "|"

    Dim dic As Object
    Dim newRows As Range
    Dim vSteps, key, vInterface, results '<- You could declare variables
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, n As Long

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ThisWorkbook '<- To avoid issues if two workbooks are open create a "With Statement" for this workbook

        With .Sheets("Steps") '<- Use "." before Sheets to show that you will the work in the workbook of the "With Statement"

            vSteps = .Range("A2:C2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value

        End With

        For r = 1 To UBound(vSteps)

            key = vSteps(r, 2) & Delimiter & vSteps(r, 2)

            If Not dic.Exists(key) Then dic.Add key, 0

        Next

        With .Sheets("Interface") '<- Use "." before Sheets to show that you will the work in the workbook of the "With Statement"

            vInterface = .Range("A2:O2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Value

        End With

        ReDim results(1 To UBound(vInterface), 1 To 15)

        For r = 1 To UBound(vInterface)

            key = vInterface(r, 5) & Delimiter & vInterface(r, 5)

            If Not dic.Exists(key) Then

                n = n + 1

                For c = 3 To 15
                    results(n, c - 2) = vInterface(r, c)
                Next

            End If

        Next

        With .Sheets("Steps") '<- Use "." before Sheets to show that you will the work in the workbook of the "With Statement"

            With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

                    .Resize(n, 15).Value = results

            End With

              UpdateNEW2 = n

        End With

    End With

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks . It worked . If I have any doubts . I get back on this .

Answer (score 0):

```
    With Sheets("Steps")
      With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .Resize(n, 15).Value = results
      End With

      UpdateNEW2 = n
    End with <-- you've forgotten this one.
```

As you can see, proper indentation makes it easier to read and correct where needed.

Comment: I have tried that one , But I get application error on the line ".Resize(n, 15).Value = results"